# How to fix error: cannot find symbol in android studio SQLite database

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm new to Android studio and I'm trying to create an SQLite database. When I run the emulator I get two 'cannot find symbol' errors.

I've found similar questions, such as these:
[Cannot find symbol error in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56902888/cannot-find-symbol-error-in-android-studio)

[Cannot Find Symbol Error on Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510906/cannot-find-symbol-error-on-android-studio)

[error: cannot find symbol class Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148063/error-cannot-find-symbol-class-android-studio)

But none have helped.

It seems weird because the other 3 columns are fine.

I'd be very grateful if anyone could help.

My MainActivity.java code is:

```
package com.example.android.hbpm1;

import androidx.annotation.IdRes;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    EditText editsystolic,editdiastolic;
    Button btnsubmitButton;
    private Button button;



    int systolic, diastolic;

    EditText systolicInput;
    EditText diastolicInput;

    Button submitButton;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        editsystolic = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.systolicInput);
        editdiastolic = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diastolicInput);
        btnsubmitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        AddData();




        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homeButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openHomeScreen();
            }
        });


        systolicInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.systolicInput);
        diastolicInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.diastolicInput);

        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                systolic = Integer.valueOf(systolicInput.getText().toString());
                diastolic = Integer.valueOf(diastolicInput.getText().toString());



                showToast(String.valueOf(systolicInput));
                showToast(String.valueOf(diastolicInput));

            }
        });



    }

    public void AddData() {
        btnsubmitButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editsystolic.getText().toString(),
                                editdiastolic.getText().toString());
                        if(isInserted = true)
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void openHomeScreen() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void showToast(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

My DatabaseHelper.java code is:

```
package com.example.android.hbpm1;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bpdata.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "bpdata_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "_id";
    public static final String COL_2 = "datetime";
    public static final String COL_3 = "systolic";
    public static final String COL_4 = "diastolic";
    public static final String COL_5 = "hr";

    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,datetime INTEGER,systolic INTEGER,diastolic INTEGER,hr INTEGER)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public boolean insertData(String datetime, String systolic) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,datetime);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,systolic);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,diastolic);
        contentValues.put(COL_5,hr);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Here are the errors:

````
        contentValues.put(COL_4,diastolic);
                                ^
  symbol:   variable diastolic
  location: class DatabaseHelper

error: cannot find symbol
        contentValues.put(COL_5,hr);
                                ^
  symbol:   variable hr
  location: class DatabaseHelper```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short answer

In your method insertData you have declared only 2 parameters dateTime and sysTolic, but no diastolic and hr, those fields/variables are neither declared in the class.

Thus you have an error.

The easiest solution to your problem that is compatible with the code you wrote is simply adding that 2 parameters to method insertData.

## However

In my personal opinion times when we needed to write code using nothing but raw SQL statements should be long gone, there is great (for both academic and business) library made by google targeting specifically android, it is called [Room](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/BasicRxJavaSampleKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/observability/persistence/UserDao.kt).

Of course, if your project specifications require you not to use any libs, that's alright, however, in Android, we most often use libraries for all the little things just to make our lives easier, safer and faster. (aka. RxKotlin, Room, Retrofit, Gson, Dagger etc)

Cheers and have fun coding

Comment: that's worked, thank you so much for your help - and I appreciate the comments about libraries :)

Answer (score 0):

As per my view, you do not define any value for these two field

```
contentValues.put(COL_4,diastolic);
contentValues.put(COL_5,hr);
```

Change it to below code and if you no need to pass any value for those last two columns then pass empty like this

> ""

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public boolean insertData(String datetime, String systolic, String diastolic, String hr) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,datetime);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,systolic);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,diastolic);
        contentValues.put(COL_5,hr);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editsystolic.getText().toString(),
                                editdiastolic.getText().toString(), "", "");
```